# How to create new tabs in xamarin forms web view

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to make my web-view support multiple tabs .
how to do it for example like this code :

```
browser.newtab(URL:"google.com",tabindex:1);
```

How to do it in android and ios ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. `WebView` (and its native counterparts) don't support the tab browsing. So there is not a single line of code that will resolve your problem You must create the tab UI yourself and manage everything related to it.

Comment: I know it's not easy to do it from one line code i need to know the scenario to do it

Comment: Now After 6 Months of search i accepted you answer ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to go for tabbed page. Example:

```
    private ContentPage NewBrowserTab(string url)
    {
        var cp = new ContentPage();
        cp.Title = url;
        var wv = new WebView();
        wv.Source = url;
        cp.Content = wv;
        return cp;
    }
```

And tabbed page:

```
        TabbedPage tp = new TabbedPage();
        tp.Children.Add(NewBrowserTab("https://google.com"));
        tp.Children.Add(NewBrowserTab("https://xamarin.com"));

        App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(tp);
```

Comment: I don't need multi WebView i need multi tabs with the same cookies that's user logged in